# Why an element of an order of a number field K is always an algebraic integer of K?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{N})$ be a number field,  $\mathcal O$ be an order of $K$ (i.e. $\mathcal O$ is a subring of $K$ and $\mathcal O$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank 2).

In the begining of [this thesis](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~fouquet/Manuscrit.ps.gz) (p.7 just after the definition 1.1.3 : "De plus, si $\alpha \in \mathcal O$ [...] alors $\alpha$ est un entier algébrique de K" ), it is said that every element $\alpha\in \mathcal O$ is an algebraic integer of $K$. But I do not see why...

If I'm doing that correctly: $\mathcal O=\mathbb Z\left[\frac pq \sqrt{N}\right]$, for some integers $p,q$ such that gcd($p,q$)=1.

Then, let $\alpha\in\mathbb O$, so $\alpha=a + b \frac pq \sqrt{N}$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$) is root of the polynmonial $F=q^2(X-a)^2-b^2p^2N\in\mathbb Z[X]$, but $F$ is not a unit polynomial.

Where am I wrong or what is the point I'm missing?

Comment: You need (for example) $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{N}\right)^2 \in \mathcal{O}.$$

Comment: oh! So $q$ is necessary 1! Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. If $N \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{N})$ is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{N}}{2}\right]$, so there you can also have half-integers as coefficients. (But the sum (and the difference) of the coefficients of $1$ and of $\sqrt{N}$ must be an integer.)

Comment: hmmm... I see the point, I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: If $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\subset \mathcal{O}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer